# Trouble getting newest record from grouped records

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, subquery, max

I'm pretty new to Access so I'm sure this is something simple. I'm not sure I even have the best subject.

I have an `Owner` and a `Names` table that contain data like this:

```
Owner                   Names

TMKFK    NID ...        NIDFK Last   ModDate
7721011  45             45    Smith  1/18/15
7721011  137            137   Jones  2/1/15
7721012  45             45    Smith  1/18/15
```

I am trying to query them so that I get the `TMKFK` for the latest timestamped record in the `Name` table. This is used for a lookup from a form. So if I lookup `Smi*` I expect to get `7721012`.

After a bunch of looking around on this site and elsewhere and looking at `partition over` I concluded the answer had to be using a subquery, but I can't quite figure out what to put where. This is where I got stuck:

```
SELECT Owner.TMKFK
FROM Owner INNER JOIN Names ON Owner.NID = Names.NIDFK
GROUP BY Owner.TMKFK, [Owner Name].Last, [Owner Name].M
WHERE (Owner.TMKFK=7721011 Or Owner.TMKFK=7721012) 
AND Names.Last Like "Smith" 
AND Names.ModDate=(SELECT Max(Names.ModDate) FROM Names);
```

This fails because the subquery returns the Max date from the entire table and not just the two records with the same `TMKFK`. A `HAVING` clause doesn't seem to make a difference. Re-ordering the fields in group by didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The subquery to get the max date would need to be restricted to the owner in question. Something along these lines:

```
SELECT Owner.TMKFK
  FROM Owner INNER JOIN Names ON Owner.NID = Names.NIDFK
  WHERE (Owner.TMKFK=7721011 Or Owner.TMKFK=7721012) 
    AND Names.Last Like 'Smith%' 
    AND Names.ModDate=(SELECT Max(Names.ModDate)
                         FROM Names
                         WHERE NIDFK = Owner.NID
                      )
```

Don't think you need the `GROUP BY`.  Don't know the Access syntax, but `LIKE` usually implies wildcards like `%` and the string should be single quoted. And if you want case-insensitive searching:

```
AND UPPER(Names.Last) LIKE UPPER('Smith%')
```